# Autokey error, not apparently related to my script

Tags: linux, linux-mint, python3

I have written a small Autokey script to start Firefox full-screen with a certain URL. The script has worked well for a couple of years. Since a system upgrade, it has started producing a Python error which does not seem to be related to my code. Despite the error, the script still does what I expect, i.e. Start a new Firefox window, open the URL and maximise the window.

System details:

- Linux Mint 20.1 Cinnamon
- autokey-gtk 0.95.10
- Python 3.8.5

The script is, with comments deleted and some details redacted, but line numbers retained:

```
9  system.exec_command("firejail firefox -new-window URL”)
11 time.sleep(1)
12 system.exec_command("wmctrl -r \"Title\" -b add,maximized_vert,maximized_horz")
```

The error is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File “/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/service.py”, line 485, in execute
    exec(script,code,scope)
  File “<string>”,line 12,in <module>
  File /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/autokey/scripting.py”, line 497, in exec_command
    if output[-1]==”\n”:
IndexError: string index out of range
```

As can be seen, there are no arrays in my code. I am not a Python programmer, and I don’t see what I can do to correct the reference to `output[-1]`.

Any help would be appreciated.

**Edit - Add excerpt from scripting.py**

Here is the code that actually throws the exception. Line 497 is
`if output[-1] ...`.

Is this a typo or does an index of -1 have a special meaning in Python (last character of the string?)?

```
def exec_command(self, command, getOutput=True):
    """
    Execute a shell command
    
    Usage: C{system.exec_command(command, getOutput=True)}

    Set getOutput to False if the command does not exit and return immediately. Otherwise
    AutoKey will not respond to any hotkeys/abbreviations etc until the process started
    by the command exits.
    
    @param command: command to be executed (including any arguments) - e.g. "ls -l"
    @param getOutput: whether to capture the (stdout) output of the command
    @raise subprocess.CalledProcessError: if the command returns a non-zero exit code
    """
    if getOutput:
        with subprocess.Popen(
                command,
                shell=True,
                bufsize=-1,
                stdout=subprocess.PIPE,
                universal_newlines=True) as p:
            output = p.communicate()[0]
            if output[-1] == "\n":
                # Most shell output has a new line at the end, which we
                # don't want. Drop the trailing newline character
                output = output[:-1]
            if p.returncode:
                raise subprocess.CalledProcessError(p.returncode, output)
            return output
    else:
        subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, bufsize=-1)
```

Comment: You're correct, index -1 is the last character in a string.

Answer (score 2):

Perhaps I should have posted the question on Stack Overflow, I might have got an answer from a Python programmer.

I found the file scripting.py on git, and that line had been changed. I don't understand how I had installed an old version, the application version is current. git blame indicated this is the only change in that file.

Changing line 497 fixed my error.
From

```
if output[-1]==”\n”:
```

to

```
if output.endswith("\n"):
```

Comment: For reference, the commit that changed that line is [37a69c](https://github.com/sebastiansam55/autokey/commit/37a69c1bcd91c402e040cdcf6927cc9bc6e72494) (which also included an inconsequential change to the comment just below). And you didn't install an old version; that commit just hasn't yet been included in a release. (0.95.10 released 16 Feb 2020, 37a69c commited 22 Mar 2020)